# Dynamic Array resizing in C++ Doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-arrays

i have this reSize function in my Array header

```
void reSize(int newsize) {
    T* old = items;
    size = newsize;
    items = new T[newsize];
    for (int i = 0;i < length;i++)
        items[i] = old[i];
    delete[]old;
}
```

and my main code:

```
struct User{
string name;
 Array<int> data;
};
int main() {
Array<User> x(3);
x.get(0).name = "Kmal";
x.get(0).data.push_back(2); x.get(0).data.push_back(3);
x.reSize(10);
cout << x.get(0).data.get(0) <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

the problem is after resizing, my values that were stored in "data" variable are gone.

when i commented the code.

`//delete[] old`

in the reSize function
it worked fine...so i guess the problem is when i delete the pointer it deletes also the pointer inside the struct object which i don't want it to happen..
i don't want to comment the command becuz a leak in the memory will happen...how to fix this problem ?.
Update: My Array Class .

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class Array {
private :
    T* items;
    int size;
    int length;
public :
    Array() {
        this->size = 0;
        items = new T[this->size];
        length = 0;
    }
    Array(int size) {
        this->size = size;
        items = new T[this->size];
        length = 0;
    }
    int getsize() {
        return this->size;
    }
    template <class T> void push_back(T x) {
        if ((length+1) <= size) {
            items[length] = x;
            length++;
        }
        else {
            this->reSize(size+1);
            items[length] = x;
            length++;
        }
    }
    template <class T> void Insert(int index, T x) {
        if (length + 1 <= size) {
            for (int i = length;i > index;i--) {
                items[i] = items[i - 1];
            }
            items[index] = x;
            length++;
            
        }
        else {
            this->reSize(size+1);
            for (int i = length;i > index;i--) {
                items[i] = items[i - 1];
            }
            items[length] = x;
            length++;
        }
    }
    template <class T> int Find(T x) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0;i < length;i++) {
            if (items[i] ==x) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
    void remove(int index) {
        items[index] = "";
        if(index+1 < length)
        for (int i = index;i < length-1;i++) {
            items[i] = items[i + 1];
            items[i + 1] = "";
        }
        length--;
    }
    void reSize(int newsize) {
        T* old = items;
        size = newsize;
        items = new T[newsize];
        for (int i = 0;i < length;i++)
            items[i] = old[i];
        delete[]old;
    }
    void Merge(Array<T> x){
        T* old = items; int oldlength = length;
        items = new T[size + x.size];
        size = size + x.size;
        length += x.length;
        for (int i = 0;i < length;i++) {
            if(i< oldlength)
                items[i] = old[i];
            else
                items[i] = x.items[i-oldlength];
        }
        delete[] old;
    }
    T& get(int index) {
        return items[index];
    }
   }
```

Comment: My guess is you're missing an appropriate `operator=` and copy/move ctor in your `Array` class. But you really should include the full code so this is reproducible.

Comment: @perivesta sorry for providing not enough info...i edited the post and provided the Array Class.

Comment: Seems very likely that this is a problem with violating the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct User{
string name;
 Array<int> data;
};
int main() {
Array<User> x(3);

// this line causes some problems
x.get(0).name = "Kmal";

x.get(0).data.push_back(2); x.get(0).data.push_back(3);
x.reSize(10);
cout << x.get(0).data.get(0) <<endl;
return 0;
}
```

In your code, declaring `Array<User> x(3)` declares an *empty* array with 3 elements that are preallocated. The `length` property of the array is 0. When the array is copied, `length`(0) elements are copied over into the resized storage. When you access the 0th element, it won't be copied on resize. What you actually need to do is call `push_back()` to add an element to the array so that length becomes 1 and the element is copied on resize.

Also, your array class is lacking a proper copy constructor and move constructor, which means copying it won't work at all. This means that `User` cannot be copied properly since it contains an array, which means that resizing an array of `User` won't work. You need to implement a copy constructor and copy assignment operator to be able to copy the array. You also need a destructor since, right now, the array is leaking memory when it goes out of scope.